# Wrap mat-card into a custom component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to show cards which can be expanded or collapsed. The HTML looks like this:

```
<mat-card class="case-study-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Some title</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Some subtitle</mat-card-subtitle>
    <button mat-mini-fab (click)="collapsed=!collapsed">
      <mat-icon *ngIf="!collapsed">expand_less</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon *ngIf="collapsed">expand_more</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content *ngIf="!collapsed">Some content</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

The ts only contains:

```
collapsed = true; //card is collapsed by default
```

CSS:

```
.case-study-card {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 8px auto 8px auto;
}

mat-card-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; //send the button to the end
}
```

It works exactly as intended. But I would like to have many cards - at the moment I repeat the html for each card and I have several `collapsed` variables (collapsed1, collapsed2 etc.) to handle each card individually.

I would like instead to create a custom component that I would be able to use like this:

```
<my-card>
  <my-card-title>Some title</my-card-title>
  <my-card-subtitle>Some subtitle</my-card-subtitle>
  <my-card-content>Some content</my-card-content>
</my-card>
```

But I can't find a way to define the custom subtags (my-card-title etc.) in the MyCardComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [multi-slot content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#multi-slot-content-projection).
Here's a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ce2iw2) based on your code.

Basically you want to have multiple `ng-content` tags in place where you want to insert some content, each with a different `select` attribute. The `select` is basically a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), so you can select by an id, class, type, etc.

```
<mat-card class="case-study-card">
<mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-title>
    <ng-content select="[title]"></ng-content>
  </mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-subtitle>
    <ng-content select="[subtitle]"></ng-content>
  </mat-card-subtitle>
  <button mat-mini-fab (click)="collapsed=!collapsed">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!collapsed">expand_less</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="collapsed">expand_more</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-card-header>
<mat-card-content *ngIf="!collapsed">
  <ng-content select="[content]"></ng-content>
</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Then, when using your components you will place three tags that fit the specified selector. You can use any valid HTML tag or `ng-container`. The whole tag and all it's descendants will be placed in proper place in your component.

```
<app-custom-card>
  <ng-container title>Title 1</ng-container>
  <ng-container subtitle>Subtitle 1</ng-container>
  <ng-container content>Content 1</ng-container>
</app-custom-card>

<app-custom-card>
  <ng-container title>Title 2</ng-container>
  <ng-container subtitle>Subtitle 2</ng-container>
  <ng-container content>Content 2</ng-container>
</app-custom-card>

<app-custom-card>
  <ng-container title>Title 3</ng-container>
  <ng-container subtitle>Subtitle 3</ng-container>
  <ng-container content>
    <p>Para 1</p>
    <p style="color:red">Para 2</p>
  </ng-container>
</app-custom-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer put me in the right direction but I've used a slightly different approach.

ts:

```
collapsed = true;
@Input() title!: string;
@Input() subtitle!: string;
```

Custom card component html:

```
<mat-card class="case-study-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title [innerHTML]="title"></mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle [innerHTML]="subtitle"></mat-card-subtitle>
    <button mat-mini-fab (click)="collapsed=!collapsed">
      <mat-icon *ngIf="!collapsed">expand_less</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon *ngIf="collapsed">expand_more</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content *ngIf="!collapsed">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

And the component is used like this:

```
<my-card title="Some title" subtitle="Some subtitle">
  <p>content here</p>
</my-card>
```